# In Kubernetes ingress, when use-regex is true, what's the correct way to define a route for /

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I need to define the following routes on my Kubernetes ingress :

- `my-website.com/*`      => web client
- `my-website.com/api/*`  => graphql api

I've tried to set the following but only the /api route works:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "my-ingress"
  annotations:
    "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": nginx
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity": cookie
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/$2"
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex": "true"
  spec:
    rules:
      - host: my-website.com
        http:
          paths:
            - path: "/api(/|$)(.*)"
              backend:
                serviceName: web-client
                servicePort: 80
            - path: "/"
              backend:
                serviceName: graphql-server
                servicePort: 80
```

What's the problem with the `/` route?

*I've tried to use `/` and `/(.*)` paths but none redirects to the correct service.*

Comment: There is no problem with your ingress, I've tested here using 2 application and it looks good. Did you make sure that all services is responding in those paths? Please post your services definitions and ingress logs.

Answer (score 1):

Could you after replace `"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/$2"` to `"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /"`

Also change path from `/api(/|$)(.*)` to `/api/(.*)`

I am assuming web-client and graphql-server services are running fine.

in case you still face the issue, please share your ingress controller logs for more details